# accessing file from assets

Tags: android

I've tried `File file = new File("file:///android_asset/something.xml")` and it doesn't seem to work. It worked when I tried loading up html in a webview, but won't work when I'm trying to get at an xml file I've stored there so I can parse it with `DocumentBuilder`.

What gives? I'm guessing I can't access a file like that.

Here's the `Exception`: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/something.xml (No such file or directory)`

Is it escaping out some of the slashes? if so, how do I get 'em back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed that there is a similar problem I had in the past. You have to use `Activity.getAssets().open(...)` as you cant create instance that way in android environment. Here is the [link to the forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/498137/Android/Mobile/Reading-text-file-assets-folders) that helped me solve my problem. Hope it helps, let us know if that works.

Comment: that returns an inputstream, no? how can i create a file from that?